# Using JSON to parse earthquake info

Tags: android, json, geojson

I am trying to parse earthquake coordinate from http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/4.5_day.geojson   and display it in a text view. But it is not working... The text view does not show anything and remains blank.. This is my code:

package com.googlemaps;

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Json extends Activity  {

TextView txtJson;
HttpClient client;
JSONObject json;
String data;

final static String URL = "http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.json);
txtJson = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtJson);
client = new DefaultHttpClient();
new Read().execute("features");
}

public JSONObject earthquake(String magnitude) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException{

StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(URL);
url.append(magnitude);
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url.toString());
HttpResponse response =  client.execute(get);
int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
if (statusCode == 200){
     HttpEntity ent = response.getEntity();
     String data= EntityUtils.toString(ent);

     JSONObject main_obj = new JSONObject(data);
     JSONArray list = main_obj.getJSONArray("features");
     JSONObject latest = list.getJSONObject(0);
     JSONObject geometry_obj = latest.getJSONObject("geometry");

    return geometry_obj;
}

Toast.makeText(this,"failed" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
return null;

}
public class Read extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String re = "";
    try {

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        json = earthquake("4.5_day.geojson");
        JSONArray coordinates_array = json.getJSONArray("coordinates");
        for(int i = 0; i < coordinates_array.length(); i++){
           stringBuilder.append("Some text"coordinates_array.getString(i));
        }
        re = stringBuilder.toString();
        return re;
    }
    finally{}
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    txtJson.setText(result);

}    
}

}
```

and this is XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtJson"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Loading Data..."
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my logcat data:

```
02-08 04:23:58.908: I/Choreographer(2559): Skipped 91 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-08 04:23:59.228: I/Choreographer(2559): Skipped 301 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-08 04:24:24.608: I/Choreographer(2559): Skipped 77 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-08 04:24:26.398: D/dalvikvm(2559): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 375K, 14% free 3060K/3536K, paused 92ms, total 92ms
02-08 04:24:26.498: W/System.err(2559): org.json.JSONException: Value {"features":   [{"id":"usc000mkv5","type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[159.5419,-9.7067,41.51]},"properties":{"detail":"http:\/\/earthquake.usgs.gov\/earthquakes\/feed\/v1.0\/detail\/usc000mkv5.geojson","type":"earthquake","net":"us","tsunami":null,"sources":",us,","title":"M 5.1 - 54km SW of Honiara, Solomon    Islands","time":1391838013570,"updated":1391843853000,"mag":5.1,"types":",cap,dyfi,geoserve,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,tectonic-summary,","place":"54km SW of Honiara, Solomon Islands","status":"reviewed","ids":",usc000mkv5,","alert":null,"rms":0.59,"code":"c000mkv5","url":"http:\/\/earthquake.usgs.gov\/earthquakes\/eventpage\/usc000mkv5","magType":"mb","mmi":null,"cdi":1,"tz":660,"felt":0,"nst":null,"dmin":9.404,"gap":94,"sig":400}},{"id":"usc000mktr","type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[141.0819,37.092,54.23]},"properties":{"detail":"http:\/\/earthquake.usgs.gov\/earthquakes\/feed\/v1.0\/detail\/usc000mktr.geojson","type":"earthquake","net":"us","tsunami":null,"sources":",us,","title":"M 5.0 - 18km ENE of Iwaki, Japan","time":1391826863590,"updated":1391828049000,"mag":5,"types":",cap,dyfi,general-link,geoserve,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,tectonic-summary,","place":"18km ENE of Iwaki, Japan","status":"reviewed","ids":",usc000mktr,","alert":null,"rms":0.72,"code":"c000mktr","url":"http:\/\/earthquake.usgs.gov\/earthquakes\/eventpage\/usc000mktr","magType":"mb","mmi":null,"cdi":1,"tz":540,"felt":0,"nst":null,"dmin":2.369,"gap":123,"sig":385}},{"id":"usc000mksz","type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[54.2342,39.8122,10.69]},"properties":{"detail":"http:\/\/earthquake.usgs.gov\/earthquakes\/feed\/v1.0\/detail\/usc000mksz.geojson","type":"earthquake","net":"us","tsunami":null,"sources":",us,","title":"M 4.6 - 35km NNW of Balkanabat, Turkmenistan","time":1391821880490,"updated":1391850827048,"mag":4.6,"types":",cap,dyfi,geoserve,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,tectonic-summary,","place":"35km NNW of Balkanabat, Turkmenistan","status":"reviewed","ids":",usc000mksz,","alert":null,"rms":1.36,"code":"c000mksz","url":"http:\/\/earthquake.usgs.gov\/earthquakes\/eventpage\/usc000mksz","magType":"mb","mmi":null,"cdi":null,"tz":300,"felt":null,"nst":null,"dmin":3.566,"gap":53,"sig":326}},{"id":"usc000mkir","type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-72.9583,6.7107,157.61]},"properties":{"detail":"http:\/\/earthquake.usgs.gov\/earthquakes\/feed\/v1.0\/detail\/usc000mkir.geojson","type":"earthquake","net":"us","tsunami":null,"sources":",us,","title":"M 5.4 - 7km ENE of Aratoca, Colombia","time":1391805430940,"updated":1391822811919,"mag":5.4,"types":",cap,dyfi,general-link,geoserve,losspager,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,","place":"7km ENE of Aratoca, Colombia","status":"reviewed","ids":",usc000mkir,","alert":"green","rms":0.86,"code":"c000mkir","url":"http:\/\/earthquake.usgs.gov\/earthquakes\/eventpage\/usc000mkir","magType":"mb","mmi":4.02,"cdi":5,"tz":-300,"felt":151,"nst":null,"dmin":2.292,"gap":23,"sig":524}},{"id":"usc000mkes","type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-179.784,-23.2075,544.06]},"properties":{"detail":"http:\/\/earthquake.usgs.gov\/earthquakes\/feed\/v1.0\/detail\/usc000mkes.geojson","type":"earthquake","net":"us","tsunami":null,"sources":",us,","title":"M 4.8 - South of the Fiji Islands","time":1391797565060,"updated":1391826517121,"mag":4.8,"types":",cap,dyfi,geoserve,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,tectonic-summary,","place":"South of the Fiji Islands","status":"reviewed","ids":",usc000mkes,","alert":null,"rms":0.94,"code":"c000mkes","url":"http:\/\/earthquake.usgs.gov\/earthquakes\/eventpage\/usc000mkes","magType":"mb","mmi":null,"cdi":null,"tz":-720,"felt":null,"nst":null,"dmin":5.8,"gap":111,"sig":354}},{"id":"usc000mkcq","type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[141.3575,37.607,63.17]},"properties":{"detail":"http:\/\/earthquake.usgs.gov\/earthquakes\/feed\/v1.0\/detail\/usc000mkcq.geojson","ty
02-08 04:24:26.508: W/System.err(2559):     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
02-08 04:24:26.518: W/System.err(2559):     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:96)
02-08 04:24:26.518: W/System.err(2559):     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
02-08 04:24:26.528: W/System.err(2559):     at com.googlemaps.Json.earthquake(Json.java:50)
02-08 04:24:26.528: W/System.err(2559):     at com.googlemaps.Json$Read.doInBackground(Json.java:66)
02-08 04:24:26.528: W/System.err(2559):     at com.googlemaps.Json$Read.doInBackground(Json.java:1)
02-08 04:24:26.548: W/System.err(2559):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
02-08 04:24:26.548: W/System.err(2559):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
02-08 04:24:26.548: W/System.err(2559):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
02-08 04:24:26.548: W/System.err(2559):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-08 04:24:26.558: W/System.err(2559):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
02-08 04:24:26.558: W/System.err(2559):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: `txtJson.setText(result.toString());` ? Also add Log outputs for data, list and latest after `String data= EntityUtils.toString(ent);
JSONArray list = new JSONArray(data);
JSONObject latest = list.getJSONObject(0);` to ensure it has any data to display

Comment: -1 for not posting logcat logs ... im sure that you have some error since this json is not array and you are using  `new  JSONArray(data)`

Comment: @AD. http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/4.5_day.geojson click on Viewer ... the you will see that first you have JSONObject than first array is "features" `new JSONObject(data).getJSONArray("features")`

Comment: so, how to i make the code work?

Comment: @AD. check out my ans and try it.

Comment: @Hariharan Tamilan i am getting this error "The method append(String) is undefined for the type String" in re = re.append(coordinates_array.getString(i));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
if (statusCode == 200){
     HttpEntity ent = response.getEntity();
     String data= EntityUtils.toString(ent);

     JSONObject main_obj = new JSONObject(data);
     JSONArray list = main_obj.getJSONArray("features");
     JSONObject latest = list.getJSONObject(0);
     JSONObject geometry_obj = latest.getJSONObject("geometry");

    return geometry_obj;
}
```

In your **doInBackground**

```
String re = "";
try {

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    json = earthquake("4.5_day.geojson");
    JSONArray coordinates_array = json.getJSONArray("coordinates");
    for(int i = 0; i < coordinates_array.length(); i++){
       stringBuilder.append(coordinates_array.getString(i)+",");
    }
    re = stringBuilder.toString();
    return re;
}
```

Comment: @AD. Edited check out.

Comment: i replased the code that you gave and replace it with the previous code but i still get some errors......                                          Syntax error on token "coordinates_array", delete this token

Comment: @AD. it working correctly nothing error coming in my side. Post the new codes and also specify which line.

Comment: i have posted the new code.. The error is in doInBackground --- Syntax error on token "coordinates_array"...It is in the line with StringBuilder.append

Comment: @AD. check out my edit correctly i already changed like this `stringBuilder.append(coordinates_array.getString(i)+",");`